# Trouble with @Html.BeginForm in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form that looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "nav-login-form" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginForm.Username, new {@placeholder = "username"})
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LoginForm.Username)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.LoginForm.Password, new { @placeholder = "password" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LoginForm.Password)
    <input type="submit" value="login"/>
}
```

However, when this form is submitted the controller method does not seem to be executed. It has a signature that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(NavBarLogin loginForm)
```

My form is in a partial view with HomepageViewModel as the model type. This model has a LoginForm object inside of it, which is what the form is supposed to post to the controller. The model is passed into the partial view from the Index view like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_NavBarPartial", Model)
```

My best guess as to why this form is not working correctly is because the model defined in the view is not the same as the model object the form is using. However, I can't simply use NavBarLogin as the model type since other parts of the model are used elsewhere in the partial. I could attempt to split things up further, but is that really a requirement to make this form work? Am I even correct in my assumptions?

**Edit**: 
My forum is being rendered like this, is action supposed to be blank?

```
<form action="" class="nav-login-form" method="post">
  <input id="LoginForm_Username" name="LoginForm.Username" placeholder="username" type="text" value="" />
  <input id="LoginForm_Password" name="LoginForm.Password" placeholder="password" type="password" />
  <input type="submit" value="login"/>
```

Comment: If the action method is not invoked, what happens? Do you get an error? Have you used your browser's debugger or Fiddler to see what is actually being posted and to what URI?

Comment: try this ... public ActionResult Login(HomepageViewModel loginForm)

Comment: A blank action attribute is usually the result of a bad route definition in your `RouteConfig.cs` file (the html helper cannot map the generated url to any route)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the the `Prefix` property of `BindAttribute`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login([Bind(Prefix="LoginForm")] NavBarLogin loginForm)
```

Since you inputs are being rendered like

```
<input type="text" name="LoginForm.Username" value=.../>
```

and `NavBarLogin` has property `Username` (not a complex property `LogInForm` with property `UserName`), what this does is to effectively strip `"LoginForm."` from the posted values so they will bind correctly

Comment: You're correct that my input is being rendered like that, but using Bind like that didn't seem to correct the problem. It seems to be redirecting to the Index controller whenever the forum is submitted, rather sending the browser to /home/login at all.

Comment: Are you saying the Login method is not being hit at all?

Comment: Yes, I've included the resulting HTML from that form in an edit on my question.

Comment: the `action` attribute is empty - it should be `"/Home/Login"` - something else is wrong here

Comment: That's what I noticed as well when I actually inspected the HTML (I really should have done that before asking, I would have worded the question quite differently). What would cause ASP.NET to not populate the action attribute?

Comment: You should probably post a new question for this issue (posting the main view and the partial view). And incidentally, why are you using `HiddenFor()` in addition to `TextBoxFor()`?

Comment: Have you done something odd like include 2 optional parameters in your route configs?

Comment: Yes, the problem was actually a poor routing setup and I'm good to go now. I had completely forgotten to adjust it after making some changes to my controllers. The HiddenFor was just a test to see if it helped in posting anything, albeit a silly one. Thanks for the help!